# Graph API onlineMeeting on behalf of an application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

It would be really handy if my web app could create ad hoc online meetings that anyone could join via a join link.

I'm trying to achieve this with Graph API but up against a brick wall. I can get authenticated but stuck on creating the actual meeting ... code below

I know /me is the wrong end point but I can't figure out how /users/{user_id}/ works

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$req_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$request = $client->post($req_url, [
   "headers" => [
      "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   ],
   "body" => " client_id=" . get_option("azure_clientID") . "
        &client_secret=" . get_option("azure_clientSecret") . "
        &grant_type=client_credentials
        &scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default"
    ]);

$access_token = (string) $request->getBody();
$access_token = json_decode($access_token)->access_token;


$meeting = $client->post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings", [
   "headers" => [
       "Content-Type" => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer $access_token"
        ],
   "body" => json_encode([
       "Authorisation" => $access_token,
        "startDateTime" => "2019-07-12T14:30:34.2444915-07:00",
        "endDateTime" => "2019-07-12T15:00:34.2464912-07:00",
        "subject" => "User Token Meeting"
        ])
    ]);
```

Comment: you have `azure_clientID`, that means you have an Azure AD app in a tenant. Then you could go to the user menu in the tenant and find a user's object id to replace `/me` with `/users/user_object_id`. This will make the meeting to be created by that user

Comment: Thank you @TinyWang ... I retrieved the tenant id as [per this link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-portal/get-subscription-tenant-id.md) and used /v1.0/users/{tenant_id}/onlineMeetings ... but I get a forbidden error?

Comment: Hi, pls use use userId instead of the tenant id.. that api requires you to use userId...Open your Azure portal, go to Azure Active Directory mean, then users blade, then find an user account, for example your own account, click the user account and you will find user object id in the general blade.

Comment: Thanks @TinyWang ... this has taken me a step further - though now I'm getting "No Application Access Policy found for this app"

Comment: have you added correct application type of API permission? For the onlinemeeting API, it requires `Application  OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All`, so in Azure AD you should add this permission.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJERc.png

Comment: @TinyWang - yup I've added that permission ...